# Multiple module.export in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello guys i'm having troube about this one. I have 2 collection on mlab but they're the same database. So my problem is that my code is only saving on 1 collection . what might could be the problem here.

**models/user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//User Schema
//authToken and isAuthenticated is for UserSchema of email-verification
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    index:true
},
password:{
    type:String
},
email:{
    type:String,
    required: true
    // unique: true
},
authToken:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
IsAuthenticated:{
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
},
name:{
    type:String
},
field:{
    type:String
},
e_money:{
    type:Number //this is the integer form in mongoose
}
});


//accesible variable from the outside
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

//create the user
module.exports.createUser= function(newUser, callback){
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err,salt){
bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash){
    //store hash in your password DB
    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser.save(callback);
});
});
}
```

**models/infouser.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username:{
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    index:true
},
name:{
    type:String
},
field:{
    type:String
},
e_money:{
    type:Number //this is the integer form in mongoose
}
});


//accesible variable from the outside
var InfoUser = module.exports = mongoose.model('infouser', UserSchema);

//create the user
module.exports.createUser= function(newUser, callback){
    newUser.save(callback);
}
```

**And this is how i call them on my routes/users.js**

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var InfoUser = require('../models/infouser');

 var newUser = new User({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        authToken: authToken,
        IsAuthenticated: false,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        field: field,
        e_money: e_money //temporary emoney

    });

    var newUser2 = new InfoUser({
        name: name,
        username:username,
        field:field,
        e_money:e_money
    });

    InfoUser.createUser(newUser2,function(err,user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });

        //save the newly created user to database
    User.createUser(newUser,function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    }
```

the two data saves on my users collection only . what i want here is that it the infouser data saves on my **infouser collection** and my users collection saves on my **users collection**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing something stupid . I was pushing something on heroku that is in different file so that's why my code wasn't working . Thanks everyone but i was actually doing it fine . the question above is the correct one . I'm sorry

Answer (score 2):

mmmm that creteUser function on the model its really weird because you can pass the instance of any model there and it will call its own save function.

Why not instead just directly call the save function? (maybe you can eliminate scoping problems with that):

Something like (with promises):

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var InfoUser = require('../models/infouser');

var newUser = new User({
  name: name,
  email: email,
  authToken: authToken,
  IsAuthenticated: false,
  username: username,
  password: password,
  field: field,
  e_money: e_money //temporary emoney
});

var newUser2 = new InfoUser({
  name: name,
  username:username,
  field:field,
  e_money:e_money
});

newUser.save()
  .then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

newUser2.save()
  .then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Comment: it still saves on the same collection :'(

Comment: this is really weird but, try to rename the model to InfoUser on mongoose.model('InfoUser', UserSchema);

Comment: and also, just for good practices, the schema of InfoUser should be called InfoUserSchema instead of UserSchema

Comment: it's really weird . when i try to save it only in infouser it saves(commenting the users mongoose) and when i only save it on users then it saves(commenting the infouser mongoose) but when i do both of them it only saves on users. the heck >.<

Comment: drop the database and try again, i got problems like this in the past and creating the database from scratch helped

Comment: okay i'll that . thank you . could i just mark this first as helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Add collection attribute in your schema.

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({...},{collection: 'collection_name'});
```

Comment: isn't this my collection ??
```var InfoUser = module.exports = mongoose.model('infouser', UserSchema);```

Comment: To point your schema on some collection you need to pass the collection_name in Schema creation. Whereas, model() only initialise your Schema document.

Comment: i did but it still saving on 1 collection

Comment: Go with Sebastián Espinosa. And add collection_name to Schema.